# How do I move values ​of an array from one array to another [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I move values ​​of an array from one array to another.

```
let titels = [];
let notes = [];
let titelArchiv = [];
let noteArchiv = [];

function addNote() {
let titel = document.getElementById('titel');
let note = document.getElementById('note');

titels.push(titel.value);
notes.push(note.value);
}

function deleteNote(i) {
titelArchiv.push(titel.value);
noteArchiv.push(note.value);
}
```

I've already written a lot but I have a mistake in thinking and can't get any further. So I want to delete the title at position i and the note at position i from the arrays and insert them into the archive arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to achieve this. For the demo purpose I am just showing it one array (`titles`).

**Working Demo :**

```js
let titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4'];
let archivedTitles = [];

function removeElement(id) {
  archivedTitles.push(titles.splice(id, 1));
}

removeElement(1);

console.log(titles); // removed that element from an original array
console.log(archivedTitles); // Pushed removed element in the archieved array
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `i = index`

```
let titels = [];
let notes = [];
let titelArchiv = [];
let noteArchiv = [];

function addNote() {
    let titel = document.getElementById('titel');
    let note = document.getElementById('note');
    
    titels.push(titel.value);
    notes.push(note.value);
}

function deleteNote(i) {
    titelArchiv.push(...titels.splice(i, 1));
    noteArchiv.push(...notes.splice(i, 1));
}
```